# What does "csf=1" mean in a folder URL?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, url

While viewing a Document Library in SPO, when I "copy link" for any given **folder**, at the end of the URL there's "csf=1". However, if I "copy link" on a **file**, it has "ID=..." instead.

[image: list of URLs]
*(URL's copied into Notepad++. Black are folder URLs, green is file URL)*

What does "csf=1" mean?

Comment: Perhaps, "Connected Services Framework"? If so, what would the "1" denote?

Comment: it must some sort of parameter as this was recently sorted previously it was a long ugly url which was changed recently. My guess is it is just a redirection to the old ugly url. Some discussion https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Getting-Link-to-a-Document-with-Modern-Document-Libraries/td-p/5099

Comment: Strange, on my SPO tenant I get these links for files: `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/Ebv43K_LORLRmPcljndTFb8BK6rA0G3LcuEBL2W6-DAT5g?e=lM5g7J` and these for folders: `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/Erp_tHhWhilYknYXUDf4xSMB8ne_L1NnK3REglegtb89og?e=pI0xh5`I wonder why there is such a difference in URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I have read in several forums, those "?csf=1" is an old version Microsoft carry over that got removed recently.  The stupidity of the vendor (Microsoft) is not to carry the appropriate code to support or at least ignore those extension.  The problem I am facing is that whenever I send the link with that extra parameter (which comes up automatically when I tried to share), it always brings up an OLDER version of the SharePoint document as opposed to the LATEST version.  Whereas, when we try using the URL without that parameter, it always brings up the latest version of the document.   So, lesson:  Remove the parameter (? and all the characters after that) BEFORE sending the link to anyone for them to see the LATEST version of the document.